# How can I do quick searching in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, vim-plugin

Is it possible to do searching in NERDTree window by the filenames and file content?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do `/foo` like in any other normal Vim window but you are limited to the text currently displayed in NERDTree: you cannot search non-expanded subdirectories or non-listed files.

Assuming you are at the root of your project, you can do the following to search the word `foo` in JavaScript files across your project:

```
:vim foo **/*.js | copen
```

Or the following if the "working directory" (`:pwd`) is not the root of your project:

```
:vim foo /path/to/project/**/* | copen
```

Note the `**` (`:help starstar`) that makes the search recursive.

If you want to open `app/views/foobar.php` for editing, you can do:

```
:e **/foo<tab>
```

Well, there are many ways.

Accessing files/buffers or searching across a project are relatively straightforward with native commands but there are quite a lot of third party plugins to make it even faster and easier. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is my favorite file/buffer finder plugin but you should get comfortable with the basics before turning to plugins.

Answer (score 11):

[Command-t](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) in one of my favorite vim plugins, it's ruby based plugin above integration with [FZF.](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

By using Comamnd-T and FZF you can do the search with an extremely fast "fuzzy" mechanism for:

- Opening files and buffers
- Jumping to tags and help
- Running commands, or previous searches and commands
- with a minimal number of keystrokes.

As you can see

[image]

I always search in command history by opening a new terminal and hit:

```
CTRL+R
```

In addition to searching in all folders recursively by writing in any terminal tab:

```
fzf
```

Also, you can write inside `vim`

```
:CommandT
```

But Still, I am looking for a powerful vim plugin to search inside files content. especially in large folders. if I found one I will update this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not answering the question directly, but check out [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) instead. It provides search functionality for more than just files and it's lightning fast.